# AngularJS: Scope Filter Not Working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to save trips to the server, so I am trying to create 2 scope variables at the same time but unassigned_requests aren't being filtered.

This is in my controller:

```
$.when(SharePointJSOMService.getRequests())
    .done(function(jsonObject){
        $scope.requests = jsonObject.d.results;

        $scope.unassigned_requests = function(){
            return $scope.requests.filter(function(el){
            return el.Assigned_To === '';
            });
        };
    $scope.$apply();
}).fail(function(err){
    console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 
});
```

And my service contains this:

```
// GET DIVISIONS
    this.getDivisions = function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);

        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/GetByTitle('ITI_DIVISIONS')/items?$select=id,Title&@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
                deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                deferred.reject(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            }
        });
        return deferred;
    }; // /getDivisions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning a function to your `unassigned_requests` **instead of performing actual filtering**.

I think you need this:

```
function filterRequest(requests){
   return requests.filter(function(el){
         return el.Assigned_To === '';
   });
}

$.when(SharePointJSOMService.getRequests())
    .done(function(jsonObject){
        $scope.requests = jsonObject.d.results;
        $scope.unassigned_requests = filterRequest($scope.requests);
        //or  $scope.unassigned_requests = $scope.requests.filter(function(el){
        //                                      return el.Assigned_To === '';
        //                                 });
        $scope.$apply();
}).fail(function(err){
    console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 
});
```

Comment: Error: 'filterRequest' is undefined

Comment: @jgravois: did you declare the `filterRequest` function? But IMP, in this case we just use `$scope.requests.filter` directly.

Comment: @jgravois: see the commented code in the answer, that's the alternative solution